# NullPointerException at variable declaration

Tags: java, android

I get a NullPointerException in production that I cannot reproduce locally. The stack trace is meaningless to me, because it references a NullPointerException to a member declaration.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3430)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5527)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5418)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at org.catrobat.paintroid.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:122)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7458)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7448)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1286)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3409)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5527)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5418)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

It is strange to me because the NullPointerExeption does not give a line where where I use a variable, rather it points at the declaration of a variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public ToolReference toolreference;   <---- NullpointerException at this line ?!?! (this is MainActivity:122)

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activiy_main);

    toolRefence = new ToolReference();
    ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The code snippet is a little bit simplified. Full code [here](https://github.com/Catrobat/Paintroid/blob/develop/Paintroid/src/main/java/org/catrobat/paintroid/MainActivity.java#L122). I do understand why NullPointerExceptions happen, but it never happened to me that it says to me the variable declaration is a problem

Comment: It's not possible. The code throwing the error is not the code you're looking at.

Comment: @rzwitserloot since this happens in production could it be that line 122 is missleading? Could it be that due to obfuscation and so on the lines do not correspond to my code anymore?

Comment: The exception is in the `onCreate` method. The line you're showing is not in this method.

Comment: As far as I know, android and such don't obfuscate for fun.